# Get Now() value from ADS Database

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I want to use the Database scalar NOW() value to get the date time for a table component at post time

```
tb.Append;
tb.DateTime.asTDateTime := ???; //<--Database.Now() value
tb.Post;
```

The connection is a remote connection and the server is in the same LAN as the client machine
using Free Tables - not a data dictionary

Comment: If you want the server- and client-times to match as closely as possible, shouldn't you do the tb.Append before reading the server's time and do the time assignments before calling qry.Close, because both those operations introduce delays?

Comment: im not worried about the client time i just put it there to distinguish between the client machine and the server machine

Comment: i have modified the code example so the times will be closer if that's what the down-vote was for

Comment: It's not my -1, so I don't know for sure, but maybe it's because this isn't a very well-defined q.  For example, you haven't said whether your server in in the same LAN as your client or on the internet (in which case latency would like swamp any effects deriving from the "efficiency" of your query) and what you mean by "efficiency" anyway.  In any case, I don't see how you can expect to retrieve the server's time without opening some kind of query or communicating with the server in some other way.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a way to do it from the connection or table component which is already open, rather than opening and closing a query. ill update the question again

Comment: Can you set the default value to now() in ADS? This way you wont even need to set DTValue when you use Post

Comment: looks like you can only set a default value if you use a DataDictionary we are using free tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TADSConnection.GetServerTime` method, even using free tables. (Presuming, of course, that you've got a `TADSConnection` in use for your tables.)

```
tb.Insert;
tb.DateTimeField.AsDateTime := myConnection.GetServerTime;
tb.Post;
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for, TY